# passing in a class instance as another class parameter

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

```
Course newCourse(id,instructor[id2],name,dept);
Course::courseList.insert(std::pair<int,Course>(id,newCourse));
```

This is the part of the code where I call the constructor of the course class. The instructor[id2] is how I thought it might work but it doesn't.

```
 Course(int courseId, Instructor instructor, string courseName, string   dept)
 :courseId(courseId),instructor(instructor),courseName(courseName),dept(dept)
 {
 };
```

This is the code snippet from the class definition. As you can see 3 of the arguments are an int, and 2 strings. I know how to pass those in fine but its the Instructor instructor argument that I am stuck on.

The Instructor class has each person's info stored in a map with an int as the key. The file I am reading from the build the course class uses an int to relate the course to an instructor. I figured I'd use the int and look into the instructor map to pull out the right person's name but I keep getting undefined function errors.

Example from the file:

```
0,0,Science,Dept
the first 0 s the course ID number and the second is the instructor ID number.
```

Edit: different method appears to be the same type of call

code from the method in question

```
224             string myText(line);
225             istringstream iss(myText);
226             if (!(iss>>id)) id = 0;
227             iss.ignore(1,',');
228             if (!(iss>>id2)) id2 = 0;
229             cout<<"id: "<<id<<" id2: "<<id2<<endl;
230             Enrollment newEnrollment(Course::courseList[id], Student::studentList[id2]);
```

The constructor declaration:

```
 87         Enrollment(Student student,Course course):student(student),course(course){}
```

error:

:In static member function `static int Enrollment::loadEnrollment()

230: error: no matching function for call to `Enrollment::Enrollment(Course&, Student&)'

81: error: candidates are: Enrollment::Enrollment(const Enrollment&)

88: error:                 Enrollment::Enrollment()

87: error:                 Enrollment::Enrollment(Student, Course)

Comment: What is the compiler output?

Comment: project1.cc: In static member function `static int Course::loadCourses()': project1.cc:189: error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'instructor[id2]'

Comment: Could you post the declaration of instructor and the code that loads the instructors from file?

Comment: And by declaration you mean the Instructor instructor at the beginning of the method to load courses?

Comment: @TAS I have added what I believe you asked for.

Comment: Yes, see me answer below.

Comment: @TAS In a different method I have to call a constructor with both parameters listed as class instances. I followed your suggestion but it came back with an error. Seeing as how this appears to be similar in nature I will edit my original post with what I am doing.

Comment: Swap course and student in constructor call.

Comment: .....I feel incredibly stupid.But thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the `operator[]` on a variable named `instructor`. This variable does not have this operator defined. This is what gives you the compile error.

The loaded instructors are found in the `Instructor::instructorList` variable, as is shown in the code that loads the instructors from file.

To resolve this error you must change the line containing `instructor[id2]` to use the list instead:

```
Course newCourse(id,Instructor::instructorList[id2],name,dept);
```

Comment: ok sweet It compiles. I have a loop that prints out the contents of the maps so I will run that to test and see if everything loaded properly. I will report back shortly.

Comment: Everything seems to run how I want it. Thank you!!